# How to write a batch file to download and install Firefox on Windows machine?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to write a startup batch script to download and install the latest version of Mozilla Firefox on a Windows Server 2016 machine. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Open text editor. 2. Write code for script. 3. Run it. (That was tongue-in-cheek, of course. This is not a free code-generation service.)

Comment: Type `bitsadmin /?`.

Comment: Ninite makes this way easier. And doesn't Firefox auto-update when you open it?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this batch script written by ***Sachadee***.

```bat
::FIREFOX TOTAL SILENT FTP-INSTALL
::BY SachaDee
::08-2013
::www.batch.xoo.it

@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:start
cls&color 18
md "%temp%\fire_install"
pushd "%temp%\fire_install"

@echo off
(echo anonymous
 echo.
 echo cd pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/win32/fr
 echo mget *.exe
 echo bye)>firefox.ftp

ftp -s:firefox.ftp -i ftp.mozilla.org

if exist *.exe (echo firefox telecharger avec succes 
                for %%a in (*.exe) do (echo "%%a" | find /i "stub"
                                       set $en_cours=%%a
                                       if !errorlevel!==0 (del "!$en_cours!"
                                                           goto:install)))
:demande
set /p $rep=Le Download a ‚chou‚ recommencer ? [O/N] : 
if /i %$rep%==o goto:start
if /i %$rep%==n goto:end
cls&Echo La R‚ponse doit etre O ou N
goto:demande


:install
for %%a in (*.exe) do (CALL "%%a" -ms)
echo.&echo INSTALLATION TERMINEE
pause

:end
del /q "%temp%\fire_install"\*.*
endlocal
popd
```

Comment: This, of course, assumes you want the French version of Firefox. You may want to tweak as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best code but it should work OK for what it sounds like you need. I just quickly made put it together. There might be a problem of where it asks you if you want to keep or discard the file due to the fact that it is an .exe file. I will still put in the code that would work without this problem. Change `"dir=C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads"` to the directory where your downloads go, I.E. `C:\Users\Jim\Downloads`.

```
@echo off
title Download Firefox Newest Version
color 07

rem ---- Easily change site download and directory ----
set "dir=C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads"
set "download=https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?scene=2"

echo Opening Firefox Download... (%download%)

rem ---- Checks if file exists and if it does, start it ----
:openloop
pause
if exist %dir% (
    rem Firefox Exists
    cd %dir%
    echo Starting Firefox Installer.exe
    start Firefox Installer.exe
    exit 
) else (
    rem Firefox doesn't exist
    goto openloop
)

echo Whoops, something went wrong
pause >nul
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Readme.txt of Mozilla Firefox](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/latest/README.txt) for downloading the lastest version of firefox using a third party like **wget** or **curl**

```
Please use download.mozilla.org to retrieve the latest Firefox release.
For example, if you wish to download the US English installer for Windows (32bit)
the url is
   https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win&lang=en-US

This could be pasted into the location bar of a browser, or used with curl or wget,  e.g. 
wget -O FirefoxSetup.exe "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win&lang=en-US"

For other operating systems replace 'os=win' with:
   Windows 64bit              os=win64
   OS X                       os=osx
   Linux x86_64               os=linux64
   Linux i686                 os=linux

For other languages replace 'lang=en-US' with:
   Acholi                     lang=ach
   Afrikaans                  lang=af
   Albanian                   lang=sq
   Arabic                     lang=ar
   Aragonese                  lang=an
   Armenian                   lang=hy-AM
   Assamese                   lang=as
   Asturian                   lang=ast
   Azerbaijani                lang=az
   Basque                     lang=eu
   Belarusian                 lang=be
   Bengali (Bangladesh)       lang=bn-BD
   Bengali (India)            lang=bn-IN
   Bosnian                    lang=bs
   Breton                     lang=br
   Bulgarian                  lang=bg
   Catalan                    lang=ca
   Chinese (Simplified)       lang=zh-CN
   Chinese (Traditional)      lang=zh-TW
   Croatian                   lang=hr
   Czech                      lang=cs
   Danish                     lang=da
   Dutch                      lang=nl
   English (British)          lang=en-GB
   English (South African)    lang=en-ZA
   Esperanto                  lang=eo
   Estonian                   lang=et
   Finnish                    lang=fi
   French                     lang=fr
   Frisian                    lang=fy-NL
   Fulah                      lang=ff
   Gaelic (Scotland)          lang=gd
   Galician                   lang=gl
   German                     lang=de
   Greek                      lang=el
   Gujarati (India)           lang=gu-IN
   Hebrew                     lang=he
   Hindi (India)              lang=hi-IN
   Hungarian                  lang=hu
   Icelandic                  lang=is
   Indonesian                 lang=id
   Irish                      lang=ga-IE
   Italian                    lang=it
   Kannada                    lang=kn
   Kazakh                     lang=kk
   Khmer                      lang=km
   Korean                     lang=ko
   Latvian                    lang=lv
   Ligurian                   lang=lij
   Lithuanian                 lang=lt
   Lower Sorbian              lang=dsb
   Macedonian                 lang=mk
   Maithili                   lang=mai
   Malay                      lang=ms
   Malayalam                  lang=ml
   Marathi                    lang=mr
   Norwegian (BokmÃ¥l)        lang=nb-NO
   Norwegian (Nynorsk)        lang=nn-NO
   Oriya                      lang=or
   Persian                    lang=fa
   Polish                     lang=pl
   Portuguese (Brazilian)     lang=pt-BR
   Portuguese (Portugal)      lang=pt-PT
   Punjabi (India)            lang=pa-IN
   Romanian                   lang=ro
   Romansh                    lang=rm
   Russian                    lang=ru
   Serbian                    lang=sr
   Sinhala                    lang=si
   Slovak                     lang=sk
   Slovenian                  lang=sl
   Songhai                    lang=son
   Spanish (Argentina)        lang=es-AR
   Spanish (Chile)            lang=es-CL
   Spanish (Mexico)           lang=es-MX
   Spanish (Spain)            lang=es-ES
   Swedish                    lang=sv-SE
   Tamil                      lang=ta
   Telugu                     lang=te
   Thai                       lang=th
   Turkish                    lang=tr
   Ukrainian                  lang=uk
   Upper Sorbian              lang=hsb
   Uzbek                      lang=uz
   Vietnamese                 lang=vi
   Welsh                      lang=cy
   Xhosa                      lang=xh
```

And here is another batch file using powershell to download the firefox setup with admin rights :

```bat
@echo off
Mode 80,5 & color 0A
Title Downloading Firefox Setup from web using powershell and batch by Hackoo 2018
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment" >nul 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo(
ECHO                      **************************************
ECHO                       Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                      **************************************

    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
   echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

   "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
   del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
   exit /B

:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Mode 110,3 & color 0A
Set "URL=http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/57.0.4/win32/en-US/Firefox Setup 57.0.4.exe"
Set "FileLocation=%userprofile%\Desktop\Firefox Setup 57.0.4.exe"
echo(
echo         Please wait a while ... Downloading file to "%FileLocation%"
Call :BalloonTip 'information' 10 '"Downloading Firefox Setup.exe"' "'Please wait... Downloading Firefox Setup.exe....'" 'info' 4
Call :Download "%url%" "%FileLocation%"
If "%errorlevel%" EQU "1" ( 
    Color 0C
    echo There is an error occured ! & Timeout /T 4 /Nobreak>nul & exit
) else (
    If exist "%FileLocation%" Start "" "%FileLocation%"
)
Exit
::*********************************************************************************
:Download <url> <File>
Powershell.exe -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%2')"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:BalloonTip $notifyicon $time $title $text $icon $Timeout
PowerShell  ^
  [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms') ^| Out-Null; ^
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing') ^| Out-Null; ^
$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon; ^
  $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::%1; ^
  $notify.visible = $true; ^
  $notify.showballoontip(%2,%3,%4,%5); ^
  Start-Sleep -s %6; ^
  $notify.Dispose()
%End PowerShell%
exit /B
::********************************************************************************
```